# Select/Unselect images in a list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am creating an album feature in which the user can select photos from a group of photos, then apply them to a folder. The issue is, I am having trouble selecting specific photos and applying certain attributes to them (mainly css style, I want a border around the image when selected).

Here is the html/jquery:

HTML

```
<div class="demo-gallery">
  <ul id="lightgallery" class="list-unstyled grid">
    <?php foreach ( $media_items as $item ): ?>
      <li>
         <img class="img-responsive" id="lazy" data-src="<?php echo $item->image_path_sd; ?>">
      </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
var picture = document.querySelectorAll('#lazy');
$(picture).each(function () {
    $(document).on('click', /*???*/, function () {
        if ($(/*???*/).data('clicked', true)) {
            $(/*???*/).css("border", "none");
            $(/*???*/).data('clicked', false);
        } else {
            $(/*???*/).css("border", "4px solid #00CE6F");
            $(/*???*/).data('clicked', true);
            console.log($(/*???*/).data());
        }
    });
});
```

My guess is I need to figure out what goes where all of the ??? comments are, however, I could be trying this in the wrong direciton.

When I console.log(picture), I get an array of every photo. When I console.log(picture[2]), it shows the third picture. This is what I want, but how am I to apply these attributes to each individual photo?

Overall: I want user to click on photos they want, applying a highlighted border around the photo to let them know it's currently selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using jQuery, there's no need to use document functions, you can grab the list of items when you select something that can be applied to multiple items (like a class name).

The key here is with jQuery, `.each(function(){ })` passes in the element itself, which you can access using `this`. `using $(pictures).each()` lets you access each individual element in that set.

So, rather than applying a single click listener on the document, you can place a click listener on each `img` itself.

To show the border, place the style in the css file as a class and use the `$().toggleClass(/* class name */)` function.

```js
var pictures = $('.lazy');

$(pictures).each(function () {
    // apply click listener to each image
    $(this).on('click', function () {
    
        // toggle the checked value
        if ($(this).data('clicked') == true) {
            $(this).data('clicked', false);
        } else {
            $(this).data('clicked', true);
        }
        
        // toggles the border
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        
        // display contents of all the items
        $(pictures).each(function(index){
          console.log('img #' + index + ': ' + $(this).data("clicked"))
        })
    });
});
```

```css
.lazy {
padding: 10px;
display: inline;
background-color: red;
margin: 10px;
}

.selected {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Replace with PHP foreach -->
<img class="lazy" src="#">
<img class="lazy" src="#">
<img class="lazy" src="#">
<img class="lazy" src="#">
<img class="lazy" src="#">
<!-- Replace with PHP foreach -->
```

**Simplified**

The other answers reminded me that this whole block can be condensed to the following code:

```js
$('.lazy').on('click',function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  })
```

```css
.lazy {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.selected {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="lazy" src="#">
    <img class="lazy" src="#">
    <img class="lazy" src="#">
    <img class="lazy" src="#">
    <img class="lazy" src="#">
```

when you submit, just use `$('.lazy.selected')` to grab all the selected items.

Comment: @Shehzad Ahmed 's answer is more succinct and easier to read, but works the same. would recommend using their code instead!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an identical id selector for multiple tags on the same HTML document, instead, use ".lazy" class selector.

then you can do something like this.

css:

```
.selected-image{
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

jquery:

```
$(".lazy").click(function(){
    const img = $(this)
    if(img.hasClass("selected-image")){
        img.removeClass("selected-image")
    }
    else{
        $(this).addClass("selected-image")
    }
})
```